# Queues in Download Accelator Plus?

Tags: download-manager, queue, queue-management

I am using Download Accelerator Plus to Manage my Downloads.

Here is what I want to do: Add a large number of links in DAP. Download the links one by one in the order the link was added. Only one item gets downloaded at one point of time.

Now, this is possible in the Internet Download Manager but my trial period has expired.

Is it possible to do it in DAP? If not, is there any other Download Manager which can help achieve this?

Comment: Considered using Downloadthemall? I'm sure this is possible using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define the number of simultaneous downloads:

1. In DAP's main window, select the **Tools** menu and choose **Options**. DAP's Options window appears
2. Choose **Connection** to display the **Connection options** page
3. In the **Downloads queue** section, select the number of files that you want to be downloaded simultaneously (in your case set it to **1**) and click Close